# going to drive tomorrow and will be driving tomorrow . What is the meaning difference?

Tags: future-constructions

(14) John will be driving to London tomorrow.

The above does not have the durative act. It has a mere plan. It is called the matter of course because of the event which is occurred without the speaker's volition.
But it can also be treated as the future durative act. It has the two meaning as follows.

(15) John will be driving to London tomorrow.

a. John goes to London tomorrow. That is the plan.

b. John is on the way to London tomorrow. I think so

(15b) means the future durative act and the far future.

(15a) means the matter of course and the near future. Although the form is the same, the time relations of the two are different. See the following figures.

https://www.englishcafe.jp/englishcollege/etense/4-4-1.html

My question: Is there a big difference between the following constructions?

- John **is going to drive** to London tomorrow

AND

- John **will be driving** to London tomorrow

Both seem to be  plan or intentions. May be **going to** is a choice John has decided it and with "will be verbing" he has been more or less  obliged. May be in the first one the durative aspect is less important?

Comment: I don't see any big difference.

Comment: but EVEN if it is not a big difference there should be a slight one so what is it?

Comment: Only that _is going to_ is a bit more colloquial.